# Reversible element of $2\times 2$ matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

What is the reversible element of
$$ 
H = \left\{ \left( \begin{matrix} x & 0 \\ y & z \end{matrix} \right)  \;\middle\vert\;\; x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}_6 \right\} 
$$ matrix ring?

I think that $\det H \cdot \det H^{-1} = xz$ and
$\det H^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\det H}$ so $xz = 1$ .

Is it enough?

Comment: You should not use $H$ both for the ring and an element of that ring.

Comment: Note that there is not "the" invertible element in $H$. We have $24$ invertible elements in $H$.

Answer (score 1):

For an element $X=\pmatrix{x & 0\\ y & z}\in H$, if $\det(X)=xz=\pm 1$ then the Cayley-Hamilton theorem tells us $X^2-(x+z)X\pm1=0$ so that

$$\pm(-X+(x+z)1)X=1$$
and thus $X$ is a unit, and $X^{-1}=\pm(-X+(x+z)1)$ is its inverse.

Conversely, if $X$ is a unit, then $XY=1$ for some $Y\in H$ and so $\det(X)\det(Y)=1$ which implies $\det(X)$ is a unit, so $\det(X)=\pm 1$. The key point is that the only units in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess by “reversible” you mean “invertible”, right? A matrix is invertible if its determinant is a unit. In this case the determinant is $xz$ so you need both $x$ and $z$ to be units. The units in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ are $1$ and $-1$. So $x,y \in \{1, -1\}$ and $z$ can be anything, and that gives you 24 invertible matrices in that ring.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.